# possible reasons for UDP packet loss analysis

Tags: c++, sockets, udp

I have two servers, namely X and Y. Each has two network interfaces, say x1,x2 and y1,y2. X and Y are in the same LAN via x2 and y2.

X and Y also receives data as UDP packets on x1 and y1, respectively, as multicasts.

There are two copies a C++ application that does the following on both X and Y. Taking X as example, it does:

1. On thread #1, open a socket that receives the packets on interface x1 in non-blocking mode. In an infinite loop, `recvfrom()` is called, Then use `sendto()` on the same socket to forward the data to Y, using the IP address in y2 as target. Finally the data is enqueue to a concurrent queue.
2. On thread #2, open a socket that receives packets on interface x2 in non-blocking mode. Those packets are forwarded from Y as in 1). Then the data is enqueue to the same concurrent queue mentioned in 1)
3. On thread #3, the business logic will consume the data in the concurrent queue.

Each thread is bind to a CPU core, so 3 cores in total.

I know UDP is not reliable, but trying to figure out if anything is potentially done wrong in my application or server setting before blaming the hardware or randomness. In particular:

- Is sending and receiving on the same socket in the same thread a bad practice? If so, what is a better way?
- If the number of packets received in `tcpdump` and my application is the same, does that make sure that I am not missing packet because I wasted too much time between two `recvfrom()` calls?
- If `tcpdump` on the sender server captured 100 outbound packets, while the one on the receiver server captured only 95 inbound ones, what can be said about the missing 5 packets? What layer(s) could have they arrived at?

**Some attempts and numbers:**

`tcpdump` on x2 and y2 shows that less number of packets are received on y2 than sent from x2, same for the other forwarding direction. In particular, packets from X to Y is more frequent (~10/sec) and larger (256 bytes) than those from Y to X (~5/sec, 192 bytes), and a higher percentage of packets are lost in that direction.

The buffer (from `cat /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default`) are both 212992.

`netstat -suna` shows no increase in numbers of

```
packets to unknown port received
packet receive errors
receive buffer errors
send buffer errors
```

under UDP.

Tests with `sockperf` between x2 and y2 show no packet drops with a setting of higher frequency of messages and throughput.

Comment: Sockets are by default fully duplex, you can send and receive on a socket in the same thread without any problems. And it's very common. As for possible problems, it could be that you take too long to process each packet received so the buffers fill up and the system will discard received packets.

Comment: Use a free packet sniffer like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and watch the traffic.  If possible use a non-switching hub and a 3rd computer for monitoring.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks! Is the buffer shared across all different sockets or not? I thought about this processing overhead. Does that fact that even tcpdump is receiving less than what was sent from the other server exclude this possibility?

Comment: Is thread #1 blocking inside select() or poll() or something instead of inside recvfrom()?  Because if it’s just hammering the CPU by calling recvfrom() as often as possible in an endless loop, then it’s likely that the OS’s scheduler has noticed it hogging the CPU and responded by lowering the thread’s priority in order to allow other processes to run better.  If so, that could lead to more dropped incoming UDP packets relative to the performance of a thread that did block when no incoming packets are available.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Sorry I forgot to mention that each thread is bind to a CPU, and there are more than enough cores for my case (8 cores vs 3 threads). And my problem is actually thread #2 is missing some packets that are received by, and supposed to be re-sent by thread #1 of the other server. Could the OS's scheduler behavior lead to failed sendto()?

Comment: Each socket will typically have its own buffers and queues, but it's possible that the operating system also have some buffers on a lover level (per network card/interface) which will then be shared.

Comment: @AlgRev I wouldn’t think so, although hopefully you are checking the return value of sendto() so you would know if it was erroring out in some unexpected way.  (-1/EWOULDBLOCK would be an expected error if the socket’s outgoing data buffer was too full to hold the packet you wanted to send)